# Calling MacRuby via JavaScript with the windowScriptObject and WebKit

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webview, macruby

I have a new MacRuby application. I'm trying to call a MacRuby method from JavaScript loaded in a webView within the application.

The [Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215-BBCBFJCD) tutorial shows how to add a key to the webScriptObject that's value is an Objective-C object. Thus you can call Obj-C methods from JavaScript.

Unfortunately this does not work with MacRuby classes/methods. Below is a shorten version of my WebView's loadDelegate:

```
class WebLoadDelegate

attr_accessor :objc_bridge, :mr_bridge

def webView(sender, windowScriptObjectAvailable:windowScriptObject)
    scriptObject = windowScriptObject

    self.mr_bridge = MacRubyBridge.new();
    self.objc_bridge = JavaScriptBridge.instance();

    scriptObject.setValue(self.objc_bridge, forKey:"ObjCInstance")
    scriptObject.setValue(self.mr_bridge, forKey:"MacRubyInstance")
end

end
```

When the webScriptObject is available i add two keys to it: ObjCInstance and MacRubyInstance.

Here's the implementation of the ObjC class:

```
#import "JavaScriptBridge.h"

static JavaScriptBridge *gInstance = NULL;

@implementation JavaScriptBridge

+ (JavaScriptBridge *)instance {
    gInstance = [[self alloc] init];

    return gInstance;
}

+ (NSString *) webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel
{       
    return @"nameAtIndex";
}

+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if (aSelector == @selector(nameAtIndex:)) return NO;
    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)nameAtIndex:(int)index {
    return @"works";
}


@end
```

And here's what's supposed to be the same thing in Ruby:

```
class MacRubyBridge

    def nameAtIndex(i)
        return "fails"
    end

    def self.webScriptNameForSelector(sel)
        return "nameAtIndex";
    end


    def self.isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript(sel)
        if (sel == :nameAtIndex) 
            false
        else
            true
        end
    end

end
```

The only problem is the Objective-C implementation works fine. On the JS side you can call:

```
window.ObjCInstance.nameAtIndex_(1)
```

Which returns the string "works".

But the MacRuby implementation fails. When you call:

```
window.MacRubyInstance.nameAtIndex_(1)
```

You get:

**Result of expression 'window.MacRubyInstance.nameAtIndex_' [undefined] is not a function**

The `webScriptNameForSelector` and `isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript` methods never get called on the MacRuby implementation. I think that's the problem, but I don't know why they aren't getting called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I showed how to do that in [this tutorial/blog post](http://merbist.com/2010/10/19/macruby-webkit-and-js/).

My guess is that in your case, the following code is the problem:

```
    def self.isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript(sel)
     if (sel == :nameAtIndex) 
         false
     else
        true
     end
   end
```

The selector sent as an argument is more than likely not equal to the symbol your put. Try to return false for all and see if that works. Try:

```
def self.isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript(sel); false end
```

Also, hopefully my example will help you fix this issue.

Comment: Great post, saved my day! The biggest problem I found is that the delegate is webView:didFinishLoadForFrame in ObjC, but that translates into the webView instance method with didFinishLoadForFrame parameter.